# Simple, easy to use HTML content editor?

Tags: css, wordpress, editor, html

I have an extremely simple site that I built for a client, and I wanted to make it easy for them to edit the page content.

How the site looks: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18936351/sitePreview.png

All five pages have the same basic framework, with different images and text in the center frame.  I need some kind of easy editor/CMS for the client to be able to make edits to the main content area.

I looked into converting it to a WP theme, but I'm having trouble thinking of how to slice it up since the structure is a bit strange.  I also think WP is a bit overkill for what I need, and I thought maybe someone else might know of a more simple piece of software for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: [OpenSourceCMS.com](http://www.opensourcecms.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the free Kompozer and it's easy to learn.
www.kompozer.net and filezilla for uploading the website.
cheers/robsonrobert

Comment: I think this would be the best option.  Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TinyMCE its platform independent web based Javascript HTML WYSIWYG editor control released as Open Source under LGPL. TinyMCE has the ability to convert HTML TEXTAREA fields or other HTML elements to editor instances.

```
<html>
<head><!-- CDN hosted by Cachefly -->
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
        tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <textarea>Your content here.</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use microweber 's editor at http://microweber.com.
You can adjust your blocks to exact position you want without getting into code.

Answer (score 0):

1.Wordpress is the best ... if you want to make it simple... create widgets like before content , content area, side bar, footer everything into widgets ....

http://howtomatter.com/how-to-create-a-new-widget-area/

2.Else try wordpress visual editor plugins

http://wordpress.org/plugins/plugnedit/screenshots/

Answer (score 0):

For simple websites the best choice is [gpEasy CMS](http://www.gpeasy.com) - it suports inline editing (via [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo)) and also has many other great features.